# Does a char occupy 1 byte in a database?

Tags: database, database-design

Does a char occupy 1 byte in a database?

EDIT:
If I define a column as varchar(1), will it reserve 1 or 2 bytes for me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Char(k) takes k-bytes no matter what the value is, 
varchar(k) n+1 bytes, where n = number of chars in the value, but max k+1 bytes

```
Value       CHAR(4)    Storage Required     VARCHAR(4)      Storage Required
''          '    '     4 bytes              ''              1 byte
'ab'        'ab  '     4 bytes              'ab'            3 bytes
'abcd'      'abcd'     4 bytes              'abcd'          5 bytes
'abcdefgh'  'abcd'     4 bytes              'abcd'          5 bytes
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/char.html

Answer (score 4):

depends on what kind of char is it. if type of string is char/varchar then 1 byte if unicode: nchar/nvarchar then most probably 2 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the RDBMS system, and how you define the column. You certainly could define one that only requires one byte of storage space [in SQL Server, it'd be CHAR(1) ]. Overhead for row headers, null bitmasks, possibly indexing uniquefication, and lots of other cruft can complicate things, but yeah, you should be able to create a column that's one byte wide.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you specify the length of the `char` field as one, and the database is using a codepage based character mapping so that each character is represented as one byte.

If the database for example is set up to use UTF-8 for storing characters, each character will take anything from one to five bytes depending on what character it is.

However, the `char` data type is rather old, some databases may actually store a `char(1)` fields the same way as a `varchar(1)` field. In that case the field will also need a length, so it will take up at least one or two bytes depending on whether it's a space that you store in the field (which will be stored as an empty string), maybe more depending on the database.